# Asp.Net-Identity how to get the access token?

Tags: oauth, asp.net-identity, access-token, bearer-token

Once the ApplicationOAuthProvider has validated the user login (in the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials), how can I get the access token generated by the provider?

I'm trying to get the access token in order to save it (associated to the user) to avoid concurrents login.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figure out some workaround for this.
It's possible to define a custom AccessTokenProvider in your Startup.Auth.cs class.

Then you can get the bearer access token from your custom access token provider as simple as

`var token = context.SerializeTicket();
 context.SetToken(token);`

Cheeers!